# Prevent Screen Scroll and Page Refresh on iOS Mobile Devices

Tags: javascript, html, web-testing

How do you prevent the screen from scrolling or refreshing when you move your finger across the screen of an iOS device? When you swipe down, it causes the page to refresh and when you move your finger across the screen, it makes it look like you are dragging the contents of the screen. (In my website, you can't scroll in any direction)

I am currently using ontouchstart, ontouchmove, and ontouchend events to detect finger movements. I have tried doing something like:

```
window.ontouchmove = function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
}
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You need to set the appropriate overscroll-behaviour.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overscroll-behavior

Answer (score 0):

Setting the appropriate "overscroll-behaviour" should* stop the default practice of most mobile browsers to refresh a page when "scrolling" beyond the upper or lower limits

```
<html style="overscroll-behavior: contain;">
...
```

or

```
<html style="overscroll-behavior-y: contain;">
...
```

if you want to specifically limit it to the "y" axis only.

I say "should" because, hey, sometimes you just don't know how certain devices are going to behave, or how well they are going to respect all of the standards ...